# How Do You Use JS Promises To Keep Requesting From API While The API Returns A Value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, ejs

I am trying to keep requesting from an API while the API continues to return. I am using the LaunchLibrary API (https://launchlibrary.net/docs/1.3/api.html) and I am trying to request the launches from the past month.

The API returns with a total of, let's say, 15 results but only shows the first 10. To get the next five you pass the request an offset and query again ("&offset=10"), which would give you the next five.

What I want to do is to continue to request from the API, while passing the offset until the count returned from the API is zero. I am trying to accomplish this with javascript Promises but I am having some trouble.

This is what my concise "app.js" node file looks like:

```
app.get("/recent", function(req, res){

    var past_launches = [];
    var offset = 0;
    var count_return = 0;

    var endDate = moment().subtract(1, "days");
    var startDate = moment().subtract(1, "months").subtract(1, "days");

    do {
        var url = "https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch?startdate="+startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD")+"&enddate="+endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD")+"&offset="+offset+"&mode=verbose";
        var past_launch_promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
           request(url, function(err, response, body) {
               if(!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
                   var data = JSON.parse(body);
                   resolve(data);
               } else {
                   reject(Error(err));
               }
           });
        }).then(function(result) {
            count_return = result.count;
            offset = count_return;
            past_launches.concat(result.launches);
        },      function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    } while(count_return >= 10);

    res.render("recent",{data:promises, embed:embed, status:status});  
});
```

I understand what the problem is: since request is asynchronous it will reach the while before actually returning, and since count_return is initially 0, it just stops before anything can be returned. I thought that using promises and the .then() function I could force the loop to wait but that is evidently not true.

This is the query I am using (https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch?startdate=2018-01-11&enddate=2018-02-10&mode=verbose). By adding "&offset=10" you can get the next page of launches. What would be an effecient way to accomplish this problem.

Comment: unless using `await`, the trick is not to use a `while` loop, but to use (pseudo-)recursion, where you repeatedly call the function that does a single unit of work from within its own callback until no units are left to be done.

Comment: You fell into the all too common trap of thinking Promises make asynchronous code somehow synchronous - although, it is true that `async`/`await` (which is just syntactic sugar for Promises) can make it *look* like it's synchronous - which is probably where this misconception stems from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use recursion (generally [not advisable](https://medium.com/functional-javascript/recursion-282a6abbf3c5) for unbounded or large loops in JavaScript as these can lead to... wait for it... stack overflow errors ).

```
const moment = require('moment');
const request = require('request-promise-native');

function getLaunches(startDate = moment().subtract(1, 'months').subtract(1, 'days'), endDate = moment(startDate).add(1, "months"), offset = 0, launches = []) {
  const url = `https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch?startdate=${moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}&enddate=${moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}&offset=${offset}&mode=verbose`;

  return request.get({
    uri: url,
    json: true
  }).then((response) => {
    const total = response.total;
    launches.push(...response.launches);

    if (launches.length < total) {
      const nextOffset = offset + response.count;
      return getLaunches(startDate, endDate, nextOffset, launches);
    }

    return launches;
  });
}

getLaunches().then((launches) => console.log({
  total: launches.length,
  launches
}));
```

---

An alternative approach would be to use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) (supported in Node 8+). It should be noted these are still experimental features however this answer is to show how they can make asynchronous code read more like the synchronous code in your example.

```
const moment = require('moment');
const request = require('request-promise-native');

async function getLaunches(startDate = moment().subtract(1, 'months').subtract(1, 'days'), endDate = moment(startDate).add(1, "months"), offset = 0) {
  let total = 0;
  const launches = [];

  do {
    const url = `https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch?startdate=${moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}&enddate=${moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}&offset=${offset}&mode=verbose`;
    const response = await request.get({
      uri: url,
      json: true
    });

    total = response.total;
    offset += response.count;
    launches.push(...response.launches);
  } while (launches.length < total);

  return launches;
}

getLaunches().then((launches) => console.log({
  total: launches.length,
  launches
}));
```

Comment: I am using an older version of Node so I couldn't use await, but I used your recursion technique and it worked very nicely. The amount of launches is never a whole lot (never more than 20-30) so stack overflow shouldn't be a problem (if it's coded right which I'm pretty sure it is).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with some promise pool orchestration which you can get for free with something like [es6-promise-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-pool). Below an example how can be done:

```
const PromisePool = require('es6-promise-pool')

let count_return = -1;

var promiseProducer = function () {
    if (count_return === -1 || count_return >= 10) {
        var past_launch_promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            request(url, function(err, response, body) {
                ...
            });
         }).then(function(result) {
             count_return = result.count;
             ...
         },  function(err) {
             ... // you could set count_return to -1 here for an early exit
         });

         return past_launch_promise; // keep going
    }

    return null; // we're done, tell the promise pool to stop now
}

const concurrency = 1; // only 1 concurrent promise as we want "synchronous like" processing

// Create a pool. 
const pool = new PromisePool(promiseProducer, concurrency);

// Start the pool. 
const poolPromise = pool.start();

// Wait for the pool to settle. 
poolPromise.then(function () {
    res.render ...;  
}, function (error) { ... });
```